# Htaccess file not working on phpmyadmin.ovh.net

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I use codeigniter for my website buliding, after following the process to remove index.php file, everything work properly on localhost but  when i host my site on phpmyadmin.ovh.net it's not working anymore, i can't reach any link. Can somebody help me ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: `$config[base_url]` in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'`, `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: What does "not working anymore" mean? Do you get a blank page or an error message or something else?